# spring-boot unit testing get application properties

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, properties

I'm new to spring-boot, currently trying to develop a kafka producer
I want to test method that use value define in properties file. but it show value is null how solve this.I have added my property files to separate resource file in test folder also
[this is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b4yi.png)

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class KafkaProducerImplTest {
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    void check() {
        KafkaProducerImpl kpi = new KafkaProducerImpl();
        kpi.check();
    }
    }

    
    @Service
    public class KafkaProducerImpl implements KafkaProducerInterface
    {
    @Value("${kafka.brokers.local}")
    private String kafkaBrokers;
    @Value("${schema-registry}")
    private String schemaRegistry;

    private Properties config()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers);
        props.setProperty("acks", "1");
        props.setProperty("reties", "10");
        props.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());                
        props.setProperty("value.serializer",Serializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty("schema.registry.url",schemaRegistry);
        return props;
    }

    public <K,T>KafkaProducer<K,T> getProducer()
    {
        return new KafkaProducer<>(config());
    }

    public <T>ProducerRecord createRecord(String Topic,T msg)
    {
        return new ProducerRecord<>(
                Topic,msg
        );
    }


    public void sendMessage(KafkaProducer producer,ProducerRecord record)
    {
        producer.send(record, (recordMetadata, e) -> {
            if (e == null){
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        });

        producer.flush();
    }
    public void closeProducer(KafkaProducer producer){
        producer.close();
    }
    public void check(){
        System.out.println(schemaRegistry);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance yourself instead of getting the Spring managed `KafkaProducerImpl` instance.

Comment: ok how can i take spring managed instance.because when i try get instance through @Autowired it gives error

Comment: You should autowired the `KafkaProducerInterface` instead of the `Impl` and your test needs `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

finally i find way, thanks everyone helping me.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class KafkaProducerImplTest {
@Autowired
private KafkaProducerInterface kpi;

@Test
public void check() {
 kpi.check();       
}
```

}

Comment: Not different from the answer I posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate you test class with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) which will load application context for you and instantiate the spring beans. To add spring boot support add @SpringBootTest(Which you already have).

You'll have to remove this line

```
"KafkaProducerImpl kpi = new KafkaProducerImpl();"
```

and autowire using interface reference instead. Something like this:

```
@Autowired
KafkaProducerInterface kpi;
```

I'm assuming you have the properties used here(ex. "kafka.brokers.local") defined in your test properties file.

Comment: i have change my code as you said now i get, java.lang.NullPointerException